# Moving html tables (ordering / reordering their positions)

Tags: jquery

How can I move entire html table? I found many examples for row or column moving. I  couldn't find any for table moving. What I mean, if I have three tables (1,2,3), I'd like to change their order, and change their place as I need. My tables have same classes but different ids. They also have the same number of rows and columns.

Please ask if it is not clear.

Here is an example code: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/04c9851d/).

```
<table class="tbstyle" id="table1">
<tr><th colspan="4">Table1</tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
</table>


<table class="tbstyle" id="table2">
<tr><th colspan="4">Table2</tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
</table>


<table class="tbstyle" id="table3">
<tr><th colspan="4">Table3</tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
</table>
```

and Css:

```
.tbstyle {
 border: 1px solid black;
 margin:10px;
 float:left;
}

.tbstyle td, th {
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use jQuery UI sortable

```js
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
```

```css
#sortable > div {
  width:300px; float:left;
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <div id="sortable">  
  <div class="ui-state-default">
 
  <table class="tbstyle" id="table1">
<tr><th colspan="4">Table1</tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
</table>
</div>
  <div class="ui-state-default">

<table class="tbstyle" id="table2">
<tr><th colspan="4">Table2</tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
</table>
</div>
  <div class="ui-state-default">

<table class="tbstyle" id="table3">
<tr><th colspan="4">Table3</tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
</table> </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: thank you. Would it be possible to make it without a button? Instead, can I move them by clicking and dragging to the new position? because with many tables, it'd be really hard to do it this way.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Ercan Peker. I will use that. have a great day!

Comment: i'm glad if it helps.